# Get all filtered values in crossfilter

Tags: javascript, crossfilter

I have this cf:

```js
const paymentsCf = crossfilter([
  {id: 1, quantity: 2, total: 190, tip: 100, type: "tab"},
  {id: 2, quantity: 2, total: 190, tip: 100, type: "tab"},
  {id: 3, quantity: 1, total: 300, tip: 200, type: "visa"}
]);
```

and I'm creating a dimension by ID and filtering it like this:

```js
const dimension = paymentsCf.dimension(({ id }) => id);
dimension.filter(2);
```

If I do `console.log(paymentsCf.groupAll().value())` fair enough I see `1`.

But how can I access the whole filtered object to get the quantity, total, tip and type?

I know I can do `feedbackCf.all()` but that shows me all the 3 objects. Not only the filtered one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add the `top()` method to expose the result:

```js
const dimension = paymentsCf.dimension(({ id }) => id);
const res = dimension.filter(2);
res.top(1);
```

output:

```
[ { id: 2, quantity: 2, total: 190, tip: 100, type: 'tab' } ]
```

Comment: As of 1.4 there is also [crossfilter.allFiltered()](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#crossfilter_allFiltered). Same effect but not sorted and you don’t need to specify how many results you want.